# Taylor expansion with change of variables question.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Find the Taylor polynomial of order 3 of
>   $$f(x,y) = (x - 1)^{2} + \sin(\pi y) + x \ln(y)$$
>   based at $(x,y) = (2,1)$.

So I'm really lazy and don't want to take the derivative of that, so let $u= x-2$ and $v= y-1$

$$f(x,y) = (u+1)^{2} + \sin(\pi v+\pi)) + u\ln(v+1) + 2 \ln(v+1)$$

$$\sin(\pi v+\pi)= -\sin(\pi v) + 0$$

$$f(x,y) = (u+1)^{2} - \sin(\pi v) + u\ln(v+1) + 2 \ln(v+1)$$

$$\ln(v+1) =   v -v^{2}/2 +v^{3}/3$$

$$\sin(\pi v) =  \pi [v-v^{3}/6]$$

$$(u+1)^{2} = 1 + 2(u) + 2u^{2}$$

$$1 + 2(u) + 2u^{2} - \pi [v-v^{3}/6] + u[v -v^{2}/2 +v^{3}/3] + 2[v -v^{2}/2 +v^{3}/3]$$

so all the 3rd order or less terms are

$$1 + 2(u) + 2u^{2} - \pi [v-v^{3}/6] + uv -uv^{2}/2 + 2[v -v^{2}/2 +v^{3}/3]$$

can i just sub back in now?
$$1 + 2(x-2) + 2(x-2)^{2} - \pi [y-1-(y-1)^{3}/6] + (x-2)(y-1) -(x-2)(y-1)^{2}/2 + 2[y-1 -(y-1)^{2}/2 +(y-1)^{3}/3]$$

Comment: Just take the derivatives.

Comment: dam i wanted to avoid that, that why i shifted it =(
 I'll go Google the formula for Taylor series lol  see if i can find how to take the derivative. thx

Comment: LaTeX tip: Most function names are supposed to be upright, and you can get the common ones by preceding it with a backslash, e.g. `\sin(x)` instead of `sin(x)`. If it is not built-in, you can use the `\mathrm` command, e.g. `\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)`. You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: sorry i try with what i can not a computer person just kinda learn from the random things i happen to click edit on.

Comment: I still don't really understand why i can't shift this, these derivatives are really ugly compared to using the formula that someone stuck in my head?

Comment: is it supposed to be 1+2u+2u^2 I am working on the same question and I believe it is just 1+2u+u^2

Comment: There is a mistake: $(1+u)^2=1+2u+u^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is actually an easy one where the variables are not badly intertwined. And it only involves well-known [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables) in one variable:
$$
\ln (1+u)=\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{u^n}{n}\qquad\forall -1<u\leq 1
$$
and
$$
\sin v=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\frac{v^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\qquad \forall v\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\ln y=\ln(1+(y-1))=\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(y-1)^n}{n}\qquad\forall 0<y\leq 2
$$
and
$$
\sin(\pi y)=\sin(\pi +\pi(y-1))=-\sin(\pi(y-1))
$$
$$
=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\pi^{2n+1}(y-1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\qquad \forall y\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Finally
$$
(x-1)^2=(1+(x-2))^2=1+2(x-2)+(x-2)^2.
$$

Now you just have to plug these back in $f(x,y)$ and you are done.

You get:
$$
f(x,y)=(x-1)^2+\sin(\pi y)+((x-2)+2)\ln y= (x-1)^2+\sin (\pi y)+(x-2)\ln y+2\ln y
$$
$$
=1+2(x-2)+(x-2)^2-\pi(y-1)+\frac{\pi^3}{6}(y-1)^3+(x-2)(y-1)
$$
$$
-\frac{1}{2}(x-2)(y-1)^2+2(y-1)-(y-1)^2+\frac{2}{3}(y-1)^3.
$$

Comment: isn't that the same as what i have already done?  how do i deal with the extra variables that were outside ?

Comment: @Faust7 I had not noticed your computations... For your second question, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Write $x:=2+\xi$, $\ y:=1+\eta$. Then
$$\eqalign{\tilde f(\xi,\eta)&=(1+\xi)^2+\sin(\pi+\pi\eta)+(2+\xi)\log(1+\eta) \cr
&=1+2\xi+\xi^2-\pi\eta+{\pi^3\eta^3\over6}+(2+\xi)\left(\eta-{\eta^2\over2}+{\eta^3\over3}\right) +\ {\rm terms\ of\ order\ }\geq4\cr
&=1 +2\xi+(2-\pi)\eta+\xi^2+\xi\eta-\eta^2-{1\over2}\xi\eta^2+\left({\pi^3\over6}+{2\over3}\right)\eta^3+\ {\rm terms\ of\ order\ }\geq4\ .
\cr }$$ 
This is the Taylor expansion you are looking for, expressed in the "local variables" $\xi$, $\eta$ at $(2,1)$.